# Implementing Apollo Federation gateway using Express Framework

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server, apollo-federation

I'm currently working on a POC to implement Apollo Federation gateway in and NodeJS + express application. Up until now, I haven't really encountered any example on how to properly do it.
So far, I encounter a problem where the ApolloServer module doesn't recognize an instance of `ApolloGateway` from `@apollo/gateway`. I'm using ApolloServer instance as a wrapper of the gateway's instance as shown from the tutorial: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/implementing/#defining-the-gateway. However, I ran into a problem when calling the `server.applyMiddleWare()` in my express app. I came across the example from https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/master/packages/apollo-server-express#express

to be specific here is a snippet of the error log:

```
$ node --use_strict ./bin/www
/Users/evanlee/dev/federation-gateway/node_modules/loglevel-debug/index.js:32
    target[k] = attr.bind ? attr.bind(k) : attr;
              ^

TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function 'function() {
    return log.debug.apply(this, arguments);
  }'
    at /Users/evanlee/dev/federation-gateway/node_modules/loglevel-debug/index.js:32:15
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at composit (/Users/evanlee/dev/federation-gateway/node_modules/loglevel-debug/index.js:30:20)
    at Object.loglevelDebug [as default] (/Users/evanlee/dev/federation-gateway/node_modules/loglevel-debug/index.js:201:3)
    at new ApolloGateway (/Users/evanlee/dev/federation-gateway/node_modules/@apollo/gateway/dist/index.js:101:33)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/evanlee/dev/federation-gateway/app.js:21:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

and here is how I'm trying to integrate the ApolloServer to my express app:

```
const { ApolloServer } = require('apollo-server');
const { ApolloGateway } = require('@apollo/gateway');

const app = express();

// Apollo Server and Gateway definition
const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway: new ApolloGateway({
    debug: true,
    serviceList: [
      { name: 'base-app', url: 'http://localhost:4001/graphql' },
    ]
  }),
  subscriptions: false,
});

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/graphql' });
```

really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me using latest. However, I'm not using `debug: true` try without?